# Boot Clonzilla from USB on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, live-usb, clonezilla

I have Ubuntu on my machine and I used UNetbootin to download and setup Clonezilla on an external flashdisk. Now I wonder how I can run Clonezilla when I boot up? I'm running on Ubunutu 17.10. When I press ESC after rebooting it shows me the options to choose Ubuntu or Ubuntu Recovery. I tried the boot shortcut Ctrl+S then the below screenshot appeared. I wonder what shortcut or how I can open clonzilla on my ubuntu machine to be able to take an image of my disk. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: boot from the USB

Comment: @ravery how this can be done?

Comment: BIOS or EFI settings. You should see the button to press to enter when you power on your machine, before GRUB appears.

Comment: Booting a Clonezilla live is no different from booting any other (bootable) external media and has NOTHING to do with the already installed OS, if any. Honestly, not knowing about that trivial fact is surprising for someone with your rep.

Comment: @MKay Updated my question and attached screenshot when I press ctrl+s

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm not very familiar with boot related things, I apologise for my ignorance if it sounded trivial for you

Comment: No need to apologize, really, but please do take some time to understand what I commented above and then to understand how to change the boot order in your specific hardware (and yes, off topic here, because unrelated to Ubuntu). Also make sure you're using the correct tools for making the bootable media, Unetbootin may not be the one. Typically, I don't prepare any special stick for Clonezilla, I use an Ubuntu USB live and then, provide I have network access, I simply install and run Clonezilla from there.

Comment: If you want to have a Clonezilla live only then perhaps you should consider MKUSB.

Comment: Maybe the following link and links from it will help you boot from your USB drive with Clonezilla, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: The image displayed does not look like the firmware settings. Firmware setup is usually entered by pressing a function key while booting.